# Converting Docx to image using Docx4j and PdfBox causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: out-of-memory, pdfbox, docx4j

I'm converting the first page of a docx file to an image in twoo steps using dox4j and pdfbox but I'm currently getting an `OutOfMemoryError` every time.

I've been able to determine that the exception is thrown on the very last step of this process, while the `convertToImage` method is being called, however I've been using the second step of this method to convert pdfs for some time now without issue so I am at a loss as to what might be the cause unless perhaps dox4j is encoding the pdf is a way which I have not yet tested or is corrupt.

I've tried replacing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with a `FileOutputStream` and the pdf seems to render correctly is not any larger than I would expect.

This is the code I am using:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);
org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.PdfConversion c = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion(wordMLPackage);

((org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion)c).setSaveFO(File.createTempFile("fonts", ".fo"));
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
c.output(os, new PdfSettings());

byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
os.close();

ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(is);

PDPage page = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 96);

is.close();
document.close();
```

**Edit**
To give more context on this situation, this code is being run in a grails web-application. I have tried several different variants of this code, including nulling out everything once no longer needed, using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to try to conserve more physical memory and inspect the output of docx4j and pdfbox, each of which seem to work correctly.

I'm using docx4j 2.8.1 and pdfbox 0.7.3, I have also tried pdf-renderer but I still get an OutOfMemoryError. My suspicions are that docx4j is using too much memory but does not produce the error until the pdf to image conversion.

I would gladly except an alternate way of converting a docx file to a pdf or directly to an image as an answer, however I am currently trying to replace jodconverter which has been problematic to run on a server.

Comment: Sounds like the docx4j part is OK, and that you need to profile convertToImage.  How large is the byte array?  How many pages in the PDF? How much RAM are you giving java?  Once you have your PDPage, would it help to null out other objects?

Comment: @JasonPlutext: I have to conclude that it is not just the `convertToImage` because, I can take the rendered pdf file from docx4j after it fails and retry with just the PDF and it works fine.

Comment: The Doc file I'm using as my primary test is 52KB and the PDF it generates is 38.5KB. I've set my java memory to 3GB and it's still failing.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with the contents of your byte array is there? (ie if you save it to disc, that PDF is ok)

Comment: Nothing wrong as far as I can tell, it loads in a viewer without error. However I am starting to think that it is something to do with docx4j using too much memory, the conversion from dox to pdf takes several seconds and I've even tried replacing the image conversion with Sun's pdfview and it either works and renders incorrectly or again runs out of memory.

Comment: You could null out wordMLPackage and the PdfConversion object, as suggested above.

Comment: Tried nulling pretty much everything, no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm part of XDocreport team.

We recently develop a little webapp deployed on cloudbees (http://xdocreport-converter.opensagres.cloudbees.net/) that shows the behaviour converters.

You can easily compare the behaviour and the performances of docx4j and xdocreport for PDF and Html convertion.

Source code can be found here :

https://github.com/pascalleclercq/xdocreport-demo (REST-Service-Converter-WebApplication subfolder).
and here :
https://github.com/pascalleclercq/xdocreport/blob/master/remoting/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.remoting.converter.server/src/main/java/fr/opensagres/xdocreport/remoting/converter/server/ConverterResourceImpl.java

The firsts numbers I get is that Xdocreport is roughly 10 time faster for generating a PDF than Docx4J.

Feedback is welcome.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal! I id find that XDocReport was not converting docx files containing headers, footers, tables, and just about anything else that wasn't straight up text correctly. I updated to XDocReport 1.0-SNAPSHOT, and although I wasn't able to get your code working, when I revised my code I can now convert most DocX files to PDF without issue.

Comment: the maven repository for xdocreport 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ seems to be causing our build some problems (timeouts mainly). Are there plans to update it or move it to another repo?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this timeout problems and I'm a bit surprised. I don't know any better free online repository manager so It's not likely to change soon. I would recommand you to use a repo manager (like Nexus) on your own so you can cache other people snapshots. We plan to release 1.0.0 in a terms of weeks, this release will be available on central maven repo like the others.

Comment: No worries, I think a lot of our issues turned out to be due to an Anonymous attack on Amazon yesterday, but I'll keep my eye out for the release. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Glorious success at last! I replaced docx4j with [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport) and the document converts to a PDF in no time at all. However there seems to be some issues with some documents but I would expect this is due to the OS that they were created on and may be solved by using:

```
PDFViaITextOptions options = PDFViaITextOptions.create().fontEncoding("windows-1250");
```

Using the approiate OS instead of just:

```
PDFViaITextOptions options = PDFViaITextOptions.create();
```

Which defaults to the current OS.

This is the code I now use to convert from DOCX to PDF:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);

PDFViaITextOptions options = PDFViaITextOptions.create();

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XWPF2PDFViaITextConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
out.close();

ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(is);

PDPage page = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 96);

is.close();
document.close();

return image;
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Been having a lot of trouble lately with docx4j's PDF conversion, and this could be just what's required.

Comment: (By way of an update, I reverted my own code to the docx4j FOP implementation. XDocReport shows promise, but there are way too many gaps in how it formats content (i.e. fidelity isn't good enough yet). YMMV.